# How to get file extension from OpenFileDialog?

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I want just get Image(`.JPG`,`.PNG`,`.Gif`) File from my `OpenFileDialog`
How can I get file extension from `OpenFileDialog`?

Is it impossible?

Comment: Yes, the Filter property allow you to preselect the file types required, look at my updated answer below

Comment: Curious, I'm sure you have asked about the Filter property, but you have accepted another answer.

Comment: @Steve you are right. I have a mistake.I change my accepted answer

Answer (score 61, accepted):

To filter only certain types of file use Filter Property

```
OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Image Files (JPG,PNG,GIF)|*.JPG;*.PNG;*.GIF";
```

To get the file extension use the Path helper GetFileExtension

```
if (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   string ext = Path.GetExtension(OpenFileDialog1.FileName);
```

Comment: vertical bar shouldn't be on the last character of the string.

Comment: @MosesAprico You are correct, strange how this has not been noticed for all this time

Answer (score 11):

What about

```
Path.GetExtension(ofd.FileName);
```

Comment: Note: the Path class is in System.IO

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
Path.GetExtension(dialog.FileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Also could use Extension Method as blow:

```
public static class Helper
    {
        public static string GetFileExtention(this OpenFileDialog dialog)
        {
            return Path.GetExtension(dialog.FileName);
        }
    }
```

And simply use it by:

```
 openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
 string foo = openFileDialog1.GetFileExtention();
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2266206/Can-I-Get-File-Extension-openfiledialog.aspx), you can do something like this: `Path.GetExtension(photoFile.FileName)`

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
fileDialog.File.Extension
```

Comment: `OpenFileDialog1` douse not have `File` property!